# Visual Studio 2019 - Unable to debug Azure functions - (Desktop CLR (.NETFramework) versus Managed (CoreCLR)' debugger

Tags: debugging, .net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I have installed the  Visual Studio 2019 community version 16.4.4 on a brand new laptop

OS:- **Windows 10 Home Single Language**

The following are the .NET Core SDKS installed in my laptop[image]

The command dotnet --info  gave me the following details

[image]

I  created a Azure function with V3 template

[image]

The project settings are given below

When I  try to debug , i get the following error

A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. The debugger was configured to use the Desktop CLR (.NETFramework) Managed debugger, but the target process loaded the CoreCLR (.Net Core) runtime. To debug this project, configure it to use the 'Managed (CoreCLR)' debugger."

[image]
Tried several options  like the one mentioned in the link below

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59f880f7-ed60-4842-bc55-a9400971c58b/problem-debugging-net-core?forum=vsdebug

Comment: Try changing the following debug setting. Debug -> Options  (should open on the general sub menu) scroll towards the bottom and tick Automatically close the console when debugging stops. Also make sure the Enable native code debugging is checked under the project settings Debug.

Comment: @DavidMcLean I face exactly the same problem before and I solved It by this solution you said. It works well(I have answered). But sam's question seems different. He say this doesn't work.

Comment: Hi sam, it seems that you're resolved that issue, you can consider adding it as answer so that this useful info can help other members with similar issues :)

Comment: @David McLean's answer didn't work for me with this error

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: This has been [fixed in the latest release of Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/914525/view.html) v16.4.5**

---

The problem seems to be a mismatch in the version of the Azure Functions CLI. As a workaround, you can do this:

1. Install the latest Azure Functions CLI, from the command line run:

   ```
   npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true
   ```

   or if you are using Chocolatey:

   ```
   choco install azure-functions-core-tools
   ```
2. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks David I will try and get back

Comment: Did yuo get anywhere with this?

Comment: @sam1977 Hi, sam. Does it work? Can you reply? Thank you.:)

Comment: Will reply with in a hour

Comment: This did not help . One strange thing that I observed was that while debugging Visual Studio  shows a prompt that says  "Discovering Azure Function CLI tools version " and then tried to download the Azure Function CLI tools version . This happens all the time. Not Sure if this is related

Comment: @sam1977 This is most likely the cause. In fact, the same was the case last time I encountered this problem. VS2019 spent a lot of time downloading Azure Function CLI and then reporting this error.

Comment: How did u fix it

Comment: @sam1977 Just checking ‘enable the native code debugging’ and saving the settings solved the problem for me. And after performing this operation, if you choose to run the program, the console will appear directly, no longer out of the state of downloading the Azure Function CLI.And New projects no longer have problems. If you have any updates to this question please remember to write the answer, I am also very curious about this. Thank you!

Comment: After the latest windows update the issue seems to be resolved

Comment: @sam yeah, that's why I edited the answer. Glad you're sorted!

Comment: I'm using 16.4.5 and still have this problem.

Comment: Running "npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true" did help. Though I'm using 16.4.5 already, I was having the same error. Running the command and restarting the Visual Studio resolved the concern.

Answer (score 1):

I still have this issue after reinstalling my VS2019, downloading the latest sdk and downloading the core tools multiple times. Seems like the only way for now is to run without using the debugger (Ctrl + F5). Sometimes I downgrade the function to v2.1 for this only happens on v3 functions.

**Edit: I got this fixed when I updated my VS to 16.5.1**

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Sorry for not noticing that the solution will not work for you. Since the solution doesn't work, you can choose another way. As the error says, you need to

> configure it to use the 'Managed (CoreCLR)' debugger."

So, try to configure on hand, Select 'Debug' above the VS 2019 tab, then

[image]

[image]

---

**Original Answer:**

I faced exactly the same error before and solved it with below solution, it works well.

***Solution:***

Just enable the native code debuging.

Right click your project > properties > Debug. Tick ​​'enable the native code debugging' like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one similar issue which has been reported to [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/896770/fatal-error-when-debugging-an-azure-function-using.html). However it works well in my side with same 16.4.4 version. Since I didn't reproduce same issue, I can't provide a direct answer.

Here're some possible workarounds which may help:

1. Repair VS and go Tools=>Import and Export Settings=>Reset all settings=>No,just reset, overwrite... (Since my same version works well)
2. Hint from [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/794484/unit-test-debugging-is-not-possible-in-version-163.html), you may backup the `launchsettings.json` in project and then delete it, rebuild and debug(F5) it again.

And if the issue persists, you can try installing `.net core 3.0 sdk` and recreate a new project to check if it helps.(I have both .net core 3.0 and 3.1 installed, but by default it picks .net core 3.0 when I create the project, not sure if it makes any difference.)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @DavidG In VS IDE, go help=>about Visual Studio. For me it's:
`Version 16.4.4 VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.4+29728.190`,
`Installed Version: Community`,
`Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.4.460.23317`. Is yours exactly same as mine?

Comment: `Version 16.4.4`, `VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.4+29728.190` and `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.4.460.23317`. The only difference is that I'm running Enterprise rather than Community. Do you work for Microsoft?

Comment: Is it a newly installed VS2019? I mean I just update my VS2019 from 16.4.2 to 16.4.4, and it all works well. If your issue occurs when you recently installed one VS2019 16.4.4 directly, I think there's possibility that something is wrong with Azure Functions related component in 16.4.4 version. If so, let me know and I'm willing to configure one new machine and install one new VS2019 to check that...

Comment: It's relatively new, I formatted my machine in December.

Comment: Got it, I'll try to configure one brand new machine to check if it makes any difference. It may take some time and I'll be back tomorrow I think :-)

Comment: @DavidG Yes and I'm willing to make some help with this issue :-)

Comment: That's great then! I've commented in the DC issue you linked too, seems to be the same problem.

Comment: Looks like this issue happens in newly installed VS2019. I had another laptop that had a older version of VS2019 community edition and i upgraded it to  16.4.4 . I had no issues.

The issue happened when i installed VS2019 16.4.4 on a new machine

Comment: @sam1977 I just created one new window10 1903 VM and installed vs2019 16.4.4, but it still works well... I'm stuck at how to reproduce the issue. You may try DavidG's answer above to check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I have upgraded **visual studio 2019 to 16.4.4** and it resolved my issue. that was the bug by visual studio 2019 in 16.3 versions. please upgrade visual studio. it will definitely resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, friend. Thanks for your contribution. But sam have already update to 16.4.4. So this is not the solution. But also thanks.:)

Comment: Yes, like @BowmanZhu I was already on the latest version. I have found a workaround though, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved with the next upgrade of Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score -1):

Trying Install the v3.x Core Tools package from the command line run `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3`.

Reference: [Use npm to install Core Tools on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows#v2)